# How to return failure after rollback in Mutiny Pipeline with Panache

Tags: hibernate, quarkus-panache, mutiny, hibernate-reactive

Currently learning mutiny and transactions with hibernate-reactive. I need to save **Mess** Object in database and if there is a specific condition I want to roll back the transaction sending some kind of failure message as return parameter of the **save** method.

How could I produce **Failure or Exception**. What would be the best practice in such cases.
Could you please show me an example using this code snippet.

```
public Uni<Mess> save(Mess mess) {
            return Panache.withTransaction(() -> {
                            if(mess.message.equals("Hello World")){
                                Panache.currentTransaction().invoke(Transaction::markForRollback).subscribe().with(item -> Log.info("Transaction is marked for roll-back"));
                            }
                            return persist(mess);
                            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you consider this an exception or not.

You can create a failed uni using `Uni.createFrom().failed(...)`.
So, one way to rewrite your example would be:

```
public Uni<Mess> save(Mess mess) {
    return Panache.withTransaction(() -> {
        if (mess.message.equals("Hello World")) {
           return Panache.currentTransaction()
                .invoke(Mutiny.Transaction::markForRollback)
                .invoke(() -> Log.info("Transaction is marked for roll-back"))
                .chain(() -> Uni.createFrom().failure(new RuntimeException()));
        }
        return persist(mess);
    }
}
```

If you don't consider this a failure, you can return something else using
`Uni.createFrom().nullItem()` or `Uni.createFrom().item(...)`.

One thing to keep in mind is that the session should be discarded in case an exception happens while using it. Panache doesn't handle this situation.
[There is an issue about this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/24499) and there is [a discussion with some workarounds](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/23166#discussioncomment-3023637). But, in short, one workaround is to use Hibernate Reactive directly:

```
@Inject
Mutiny.SessionFactory factory;

public Uni<Void> create(Person person){
    return factory.withTransaction( (session, tx) ->  {
         // Now you have a new session and transaction and you can control them any way you want 
    });
}
```